# Are effective capacitance formula's valid only when initially all of them are uncharged or all of then are charged by same amount (initially )?

Tags: capacitance

I wanted to know the applicability of series parallel combination formulas for capacitors . Are effective capacitance formula's valid only when initially all of them are uncharged or all of then are charged  by same amount (initially )?

Comment: Is the discussion limited to linear capacitors ($C$ constant in $I=C\frac{dV}{dt}$) or are you considering nonlinear capacitors as well?

Comment: I guess he means Linear capacitors

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent capacitance for series or parallel connected capacitors is the same regardless of the initial state of charge on the capacitors. For capacitors in parallel, you added the capacitances. For capacitors in series, you treat the capacitors like resistors in parallel.

The initial charge on capacitors may come into play regarding charging times and when connecting them together in series or parallel because charge has to be conserved.

For example, if three capacitors initially having charge $Q_1$, $Q_2$ and $Q_3$ are connected in series (with no voltage source) then, since the charge on each capacitor in series is the same, for charge to be conserved each capacitor will end up with charge equal to

$$\frac{(Q_{1}+Q_{2}+Q_{3})}{3}$$

And the voltage on each of

$$V_{1}=\frac{(Q_{1}+Q_{2}+Q_{3})/3}{C_1}$$
$$V_{2}=\frac{(Q_{1}+Q_{2}+Q_{3})/3}{C_2}$$
$$V_{3}=\frac{(Q_{1}+Q_{2}+Q_{3})/3}{C_3}$$

If instead the three capacitors are connected in parallel, then the voltage will be the same on all three, and the final amount of charge, $Q_{f}$, on each of

$$Q_{1f}=C_{1}V$$
$$Q_{2f}=C_{2}V$$
$$Q_{3f}=C_{3}V$$

Where

$$Q_{1f}+Q_{2f}+Q_{3f}=Q_{1}+Q_{2}+Q_3$$

Hope this helps.